# Python getting division by zero

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-8

i try to calculate persentage , and show error float division by zero , and this my code

```
    d4 = float(self.qty_normal)+float(self.qty_abnormal)
    d3 = float(self.qty_normal)+float(self.qty_recoveryabn)
    if self.flag_recovery == False:
        if self.qty_abnormal and self.qty_normal:
            pnormal =(self.qty_normal)/float(d3)*(100.00)
            pabnormal =(self.qty_abnormal)/float(d3)*(100.00)
            self.nursery_persentagea = pabnormal
            self.nursery_persentagen = pnormal
    if self.flag_recovery == True:
        if self.qty_recoveryabn and self.qty_normal:
            pnormal =(self.qty_normal)/float(d3)*(100.00)
            pabnormal =(self.qty_recoveryabn)/float(d3)*(100.00)
            self.nursery_persentagea = pabnormal
            self.nursery_persentagen = pnormal
```

help me to solve this

Comment: You can't divide something by zero. Just set a check before dividing to see if the bottom half of fraction is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several expressions which have the same denominator - `d3`. Check its value after the assignment:

```
 d3 = float(self.qty_normal)+float(self.qty_recoveryabn)
```

It should not be zero, otherwise this expression will fail to evaluate:

```
pnormal =(self.qty_normal)/float(d3)*(100.00)
```

OR

```
pnormal =(self.qty_normal)/float(d3)*(100.00)
```

(depends on `flag_recovery` etc.)